# If $f(x^3 + x) = x^3 + x^2 + 1$, then what is $f'(2)$?

Tags: derivatives

If $f(x^3 + x) = x^3 + x^2 + 1$, then what is $f'(2)$?

I don't even have an idea of how to solve this problem. I solved every single problem in my text book until this question so I thought I'm either missing some critical information about derivatives or just couldn't find the way to solve.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the chain rule :

$$g(x)=x^3+x^2+1=f(x^3+x)$$ so : $$3x^2+2x=f'(x^3+x)(3x^2+1)$$ 
Now just let $x=1$ to get 
$$5=4f'(2)$$
$$f'(2)=\frac{5}{4}$$

Answer (score 8):

Well, if you take a derivative of the LHS you get
$$
f'(x^3+x) (3x^2+1),
$$
so you can solve for $f'(x^3+x)$ and pick $x$ so that $x^3+x=2$